# using jqWidgets "jqx-instance" with ngController scope-property syntax

Tags: angularjs, jqwidget

How do we use the jqWidgets `jqx-instance` attribute when used with the ngController scope-property syntax: `Controller as myController`?  [see: Angular docs on ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

for example, this does not work as it should:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <jqx-button jqx-instance="main.myButton"></jqx-button>
</div>
```

in the controller, `this.myButton` should point to the instance, but it is undefined!

Using the other declaration style, i.e., by injecting `$scope` into the controller, is lame.  With more complex applications we need the more specific syntax to promote clarity, isolation, modularity, etc., especially when different parts are coming from multiple developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the source and the ngController scope-property syntax is not supported... but it's easy enough to fix (see jqxangular.js:278).  And such a fix falls within the terms of the jqWidgets license... although I can't post any code here.